# Taking a text file and auto copy/paste/enter into GUI input field

Tags: python, pyautogui

I have a text file with 1,000 index numbers. I need to copy->paste->enter each line by line into GUI input field. How do I incorporate each 'line' into the hotkeys and repeat?

```
with open(file) as f:
    for line in f:
        pyautogui.hotkey('ctrl', 'c')
        pyautogui.hotkey('ctrl', 'v')
        pyautogui.press('enter')
        pyautogui.click()
```

Answer (score 1):

I think you need to use `pyautogui.typewrite()` ([documentation](https://pyautogui.readthedocs.io/en/latest/quickstart.html#keyboard-functions)).

The approach I would use is to move the cursor to the text field, click on it, add a bit of delay and then use the above method.

Example (sort of pseudocode):

```
pyautogui.moveTo(x, y)  # location coordinates of the text field
pyautogui.click()

with open(file) as f:
    for line in f:        
        time.sleep(0.5)       # add a bit of delay to simulate human-like behavior so that nothing gets out of sync
        pyautogui.typewrite(line)
        pyautogui.moveTo(x1, y1) # location of the button you need to press to process the current input or anything else you need to do
        
        # further processing in the GUI

        pyautogui.moveTo(x, y)  # location coordinates of the text field
        pyautogui.click()
        pyautogui.typewrite("")  # clear it out for next input
```

Comment: I'm not sure I understand the reasoning for doing it this way. My thought process was to delay the start of my code above and pull up GUI and hover my cursor over the input box. The loop would then take the first line on txt file and copy->paste->enter and then click back into the input box to start again for line two in txt file. Is this something that's possible?

Comment: When you press `Ctrl + C`, the contents currently selected will be copied to the clipboard. But, here, you don't really have that way because, well, your content is coming from a file and you don't have a way of selecting it prior using the mouse. If you really want to do copy/paste way, I suggest you look into [pyperclip](https://pypi.org/project/pyperclip/).